# UseState() throwing a white screen React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im making a react code, it is supposed to grab each value from cardInfo and put it in cards and be able to search and filter each card, this works fine and the filter as well. Although when i add the input with the const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState(''); I end up with a white screen.

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react/cjs/react.production.min";
import '../css/productFilters.css';

function ProductsFilter(){
    const cardInfo=[
        {image:"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQz3fIWD8EQsvcN8vjqj3RBFXOt0Ybr1C5v5g&usqp=CAU",title:"Lebron James",text:"The worst"},
        {image:"https://assets.bwbx.io/images/users/iqjWHBFdfxIU/iRvzLV4Dj3Y4/v0/1200x-1.jpg",title:"James Harden",text:"Meh"},
        {image:"https://i.insider.com/5a0dc09a3dbef484008b67e7?width=1000&format=jpeg",title:"Speph Curry",text:"Good"},
        {image:"https://depor.com/resizer/Wtf5Y1e8fWd5zRd3Do6yRgV58Fg=/580x330/smart/filters:format(jpeg):quality(75)/cloudfront-us-east-1.images.arcpublishing.com/elcomercio/IKJYQ4ZQ7RFWZFE57TNEBKD5SQ.jpg",title:"Michael Jordan",text:"GOAT"},
    ]
    const renderCard=(card,index)=>{
        return(
            <ul className="card">
                <li><img src={card.image}></img></li>
                <li><p className="tittle-card">{card.title}</p></li>
                <li><p className="text-card">{card.text}</p></li>
            </ul>
        )
    }
    
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

    return (
        <div>
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Search..."
                onChange={ (event) => setSearchTerm(event.target.value)}
            />
            <div className="container">
                {cardInfo.filter((val)=>{
                    if (searchTerm==""){
                        return val
                    }

                    else if (val.title.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase())){
                        return val
                    }
                }).map(renderCard)}
            </div>
        </div>
        )
}
export default ProductsFilter
```

Comment: You are importing useState wrong. Try importing useState from react ie. import React, { useState } from "react"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank Prograk:

> You are importing useState wrong. Try importing useState from react ie. import React, {useState } from "react" – prograk

The code is now working! I leave the answer

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import '../css/productFilters.css';

function ProductsFilter(){
    const cardInfo=[
        {image:"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQz3fIWD8EQsvcN8vjqj3RBFXOt0Ybr1C5v5g&usqp=CAU",title:"Lebron James",text:"The worst"},
        {image:"https://assets.bwbx.io/images/users/iqjWHBFdfxIU/iRvzLV4Dj3Y4/v0/1200x-1.jpg",title:"James Harden",text:"Meh"},
        {image:"https://i.insider.com/5a0dc09a3dbef484008b67e7?width=1000&format=jpeg",title:"Speph Curry",text:"Good"},
        {image:"https://depor.com/resizer/Wtf5Y1e8fWd5zRd3Do6yRgV58Fg=/580x330/smart/filters:format(jpeg):quality(75)/cloudfront-us-east-1.images.arcpublishing.com/elcomercio/IKJYQ4ZQ7RFWZFE57TNEBKD5SQ.jpg",title:"Michael Jordan",text:"GOAT"},
    ]
    const renderCard=(card,index)=>{
        return(
            <ul className="card">
                <li><img src={card.image}></img></li>
                <li><p className="tittle-card">{card.title}</p></li>
                <li><p className="text-card">{card.text}</p></li>
            </ul>
        )
    }
    
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

    return (
        <div>
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Search..."
                onChange={ (event) => setSearchTerm(event.target.value)}
            />
            <div className="container">
                {cardInfo.filter((val)=>{
                    if (searchTerm==""){
                        return val
                    }

                    else if (val.title.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase())){
                        return val
                    }
                }).map(renderCard)}
            </div>
        </div>
        )
}
export default ProductsFilter
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was not that I imported `useState` wrong, I have correctly imported it, but that I declared it outside my `App` function.

Using `useState` like this, inside my function, fixed it for me:

```js
function App() {
  const [authToken, setAuthToken] = useState('');

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setAuthToken(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}
```